# opening another app from my app in android

Tags: android, twitter

I have a method to open a twitter posting page, but once a click the button to do this, nothing happens. No response no anything. I have even tried a simple method just to open any other installed app from my app but it does't work.

The app doesn't crash, it's just like a dummy. It won't do anything.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Here is the code:

```
public void openTwitter(View v) {


        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            (String) v.getTag(R.string.app_name));
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            (String) v.getTag(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent,
            0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity"
                .equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                    activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
            v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Error log:

```
12-04 20:36:57.229: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
12-04 20:36:57.414: ERROR/lights(1849): write_int: path  /sys/devices/virtual/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness, value 1
12-04 20:36:58.914: ERROR/lights(1849): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness, value 2
12-04 20:36:59.229: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): usb connection is true 
12-04 20:36:59.229: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
12-04 20:36:59.999: ERROR/AlarmManagerService(1849): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 8893.012000000
12-04 20:37:01.229: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): usb connection is true 
12-04 20:37:01.229: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
12-04 20:37:01.739: ERROR/AlarmManagerService(1849): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 8951.273000000
12-04 20:37:03.234: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): usb connection is true 
12-04 20:37:03.234: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
12-04 20:37:05.234: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): usb connection is true 
12-04 20:37:05.234: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
12-04 20:37:06.919: ERROR/Watchdog(1849): !@Sync 296
12-04 20:37:07.234: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): usb connection is true 
12-04 20:37:07.234: ERROR/DataRouter(1689): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I have work it like this,

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

(or)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Here replace package name with your's.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: In fact, my app won't open any other app installed on my device. still can't figure out why.

Comment: do I need to specify any kind of permissions or? it doesn't seem to work even on the emulator.